# Problem with convert georeferenced jpg to geotiff

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff, jpg, microstation

I'm beginner with GIS tools. I have jpg file with GPS data and I need reference this file to Microstation as georeferrenced raster.

I tried use function Raster -> Conversion -> Translate with defined target SRS but without success. When recieved geotiff is referenced to Microstation he is not visibile. It is visible when SRS is set in Microstation model but problem is that raster lands on 0,0 coordinates. I enabled GDALTools plugin.

Thanks in advance for help. Regards, Krzysztof

Comment: its not clear. you have a unreferenced jpg image and you know ground control points(GCPs). If so use QGIS referencer plugin to register the image.

Comment: I have jpg with which I captured by mobile phone with GPS, so GPS data is attached to jpg.

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok for you to get cells that have an engineering link attached, than you will find a useful and free little tool on my website. http://www.centauron.de/site/produkte/gpsphotocell/allgemein.dot?com.dotmarketing.htmlpage.language=1

Comment: Could you elaborate in more detail how that tool could help in solving the question posed by the OP?

Comment: It is not exactly the functionality Krzysztof asked for. The tool does not create georeferenced Raster files out of geotagged photos, instead it creates so called cells (Symbols) that have hyperlinks attached. If you click the cell, the linked photo will open.